# How to stop fading animation of textview?

Tags: java, android, animation

I used library com.tomer.fadingtextview for fade animating of the textview it is working properly but i want to stop that animation after some seconds. what should i do ?

activitymain.xml

```html
<com.tomer.fadingtextview.FadingTextView
        android:id="@+id/headline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/goingforward"
        android:textColor="@color/Denim"
        app:texts="@array/title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:timeout="500"/>
```

Comment: Call `clearAnimation()` on this View.

Comment: i tried but not working

Comment: By looking at the library i see you can call `stop()` on this view to stop the animation and `restart()` to start it again [See the Source code](https://github.com/rosenpin/fading-text-view/blob/master/fadingtextview/src/main/java/com/tomer/fadingtextview/FadingTextView.java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can stop your `TextView` `animation` after some seconds with this way :

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fadingTextView.stop();
            }
        }, Time_TO_STOP);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to stop the animation some time then use timer..

```
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // this code will be executed after 2 seconds 
        textview.clearAnimation();    
    }
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use my library to animate views, you can use the FadeAnimation to fade any views and chain to other animations.
https://github.com/ZachBublil/Choreographer